# Unable to force the browser to refresh the display of an image if it is new

Tags: php, html, browser

I have the following simple HTML file. I update the file `my_image.png` every night at **a pre-specified time**, and I would like the site to force the refresh of the browser.  However, the `rand()` trick below does not work. What can I do to force a refresh?

```
<html>  
<head>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<?php
$fullpath = "/path/to/my_image.png";
echo "<img src='$fullpath?=<?php =rand(3,32000)?>' HEIGHT='700' />"
?> 
<br>
See the chart above 
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That will cause a random image *on every page load*. And what is `?=` and `=rand`? Did you make them up?

Comment: Hmm, @JohnConde - interestingly it doesn't, at least in my case  (the browser always renders the same old `my_image.png`)

Comment: The `<center>` element? Really?

Comment: @j08691 Is there a better way? Sorry if my HTML is too rusty ...

Comment: @user815423426 You should use CSS proprieties instead of this html tag (witch is now depreciated) : 'text-align:center;' for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you just blindly copy-pasted the code. Well, PHP doesn't execute php code `<?php` within a plain string.

Use string [concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) (`.`).

```
echo "<img src='$fullpath?" . rand(3,32000) . "' .....";
```

Note: that `rand` will force (with high probability) a reload on every page load. If you update the image daily (assuming you do it at midnight), put the date there.

Comment: Thanks Karoly. Would you mind elaborating on how to do concatenation? I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks - How/where can I use the date information to force the reload based on the date?

Comment: Looks like you're really a copy-paste guy. You should take some effort sometimes.... well, here are the basic steps: 1) figure out how this code (with rand) works 2) figure out how to get the current date 3) fix the code.

Comment: Thanks @Karoly, but if I may, it's not a fair to call me or anyone a "copy-paste guy" based on a post with two iterative questions on SO. As you probably know, when someone starts learning a new language while trying to solve a practical problem (as it is my case with PHP), you look for examples, test them, and iterate between reading Q&A on SO, the docs, and looking for additional examples.

Comment: just look at the timestamps. it shows how much time you spent on trying to solve the problem alone. I might used the wrong adjective, but I hope you see my point...

Answer (score 2):

You should do it like this.

```
echo "<img src='$fullpath?=".rand(3,32000)."' HEIGHT='700' />";
```